# PHP auto populate field when pressed tab from one field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Apologies for such a silly question but I am new to PHP and Ajax stuff.

I am trying to make one small HTML with two fields.. one id and the other Date of Birth.

What I wish to do is upon entering the id and pressing tab should automatically populate the date of birth.

The date of birth is the truncated string of the id.

Here is what I have made so far..

HTML CODE try.html

```
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <tr><td>Civil ID:</td><td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
    </form>
    <td>Date of Birth:<input type="text" name="dob"></td>
    </body>
    </html>
```

PHP id_to_dob.php

```
    <?php
    $yy = substr($_GET["id"], 1, 2);
    $mm = substr($_GET["id"], 3, 2);
    $dd = substr($_GET["id"], 5, 2);
    $dob = "$dd/$mm/$yy";
    ?>
```

I tried a lot but couldn't get it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you also post your AJAX code?

Comment: You don't need ajax for that simple transformation. Why don't you translate Civil ID to DOB in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need AJAX, Javascript can transform that. Use the onChange property.

```
        document.getElementById('id').addEventListener('change', function(){
            var yy = this.value.substr(1, 2);
            var mm = this.value.substr(3, 2);
            var dd = this.value.substr(5, 2);
            document.getElementById('dob').value = dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yy;
        });
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <form>
    <tr><td>Civil ID:</td><td><input type="text" name="id" id="id"></td>
    </form>
    <td>Date of Birth:<input type="text" name="dob" id="dob"></td>
</body>
```

If you still want to use PHP/Ajax. OnChange will still help you :)

Comment: I have done as you have suggested and it works fine.. but there is only a small problem.. when the page is opened first time the field is blank.. so when I put the id and press tab the 'dob' doesn't come.. but after I change the id again (without reloading the page) it works.. so whats the trick in this ? how come this onChange property doesn't work on blank field.. or am I doing something wrong..

Comment: I tested it with a blank field. What does your error console say?

Comment: I posted it in 'answer the question' section because it said it was too long to post here.. apologies